# Is there a United transfer bus at Newark airport from Terminal C to Terminal B?

Tags: transit, united-airlines, ewr

Does United in Newark Airport (EWR) now have a transfer bus from Terminal C to TERMINAL B so that one does not have to exit security?
Someone said the bus now stops in B, but have not found much information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes:

Take a look at the map on United's site for [Newark Airport](http://www.united.com/web/en-us/content/travel/airport/maps/ewr.aspx).